# drag multiple records from dbgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tdbgrid

I have a TDbGrid with some records. I want to drag an drop multiple records to a listbox on simple drag and drop. but after selecting the multiple records when i click on the selected records of grid for dragging, all selected records are become deselect except the current record. How can fix this issue?

Comment: The default dbgrid behaviour does not support this. To make it works, You need to keep pressing  ctrl button while you  multi select records, drag and drop to listbox. Have a look at TCustomDBGrid.mouseDown event.

Comment: If you make changes so the grid behaves like what you want, the only way to deselect the selected row/rows is by clicking on not-selected rows. If the user multi select all the rows, there is no way to deselect them (all the rows already selected) by mouse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796669/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-from-a-tdbgrid