# How do I drag and drop from a TDBGrid?

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

If I set DragMode to dmAutomatic it prevents me from selecting rows.
If I used OnCellClick to call BeginDrag it only fires on mouse up, which is not dragging in my opinion.
If I use OnMouseDown it only fires on title row.

How I am I supposed do it?

Comment: I think you might find the following article useful : http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa042605a.htm

Comment: Not really because it uses the CellClick event which only fires on mouse up. In my opinion dragging is done with the mouse down (not up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloading MouseDown will lead to the desired result.

```
type
  TDBGrid=Class(DBGrids.TDBGrid)
         procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); override;
  End;


  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    .......
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TDBGrid }

procedure TDBGrid.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Begindrag(false);
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. Been out of the office today so I'll try this tomorrow.